# Is it possible to save into the database the custom shipping address after payment is successful in using paypal?

Tags: paypal

Is it possible to save into the database the custom shipping address after payment is successful in using paypal?

i would like to save the shipping address that the customer input in the form after payment is successfull, i am using paypal method payment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  For that you'll want to use [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro).

IPN will POST transaction data to a listener script you have on your server.  This script can receive the data (which will include all transaction details including shipping address) and do whatever you need/want with it, whether it's saving to a database, sending out notification emails, connecting to 3rd party web services, etc.

It happens in real-time (in most cases) so you can do some pretty cool things with it and automate lots of tasks.